# Is it possible to store all jars in Tomcat lib folder?

Tags: java, tomcat

We have a few projects and we store libs in project  folders (each project has it’s own libs)  and we store shared libs in tomcat lib folder:

```
 ·Project1\lib
 ·Project2\lib
 ·…
 ·Tomcat\lib
```

Our manager proposed to combine all libs and put all jars in Tomcat lib folder.

**Advantages of this approach are the following:**

> 1. It will decrease compile time to .war file
> 2. It will decrease size of .war file

I feel that this decision is not the best one the but I can’t prove it. Is there any disadvantages of this approach?

Comment: Oh managers, aren't they just precious.

Comment: How does it decrease compile time? If you mean the *packaging* of the .war file itself, then that is *minuscule* compared to the time it takes to actually *compile* the .java files.

Answer (score 2):

The resultant .war application file is less portable. Additional installation steps since the webapp is no longer self-contained.

Or to argue against your boss' logic.

1. Compiling should be automated in continuous integration, so time spent is not real person time
2. Space is cheap

Answer (score 2):

Don't consolidate. Consolidation will prevent different projects from using different versions of a particular 3rd party library. This is *why* different webapps are isolated from each other.

Some libraries also store things statically (*sigh*), which can cause cross-webapp pollution.

Comment: Excellent point on the static store. Perhaps not quite as obvious until one understands ClassLoader isolation or the fact that the same "class" file loaded by two separate ClassLoader instances are considered different classes.